# Máscara em JS para Validação de Horas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masked-input, jquery-mask-plugin

Estou usando em um projeto o [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). Fiz uma máscara assim:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#QuantidadeHoras").mask("99:99");
    });
</script>
```

O `<input>` só deixa eu preencher o campo com números, mas posso digitar um tempo inválido, por exemplo, `88:88`. O certo seria preencher os minutos entre `00` e `59`.

Como posso fazer a máscara não permitir esse tipo de preenchimento?

Comment: Dá uma olhada se resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259843/jquery-masked-edit-for-time

Comment: Tentei criar um fiddle com o código da resposta do link que postei acima, mas não consegui... A propósito, nem o [jQuery Masked Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) parece ter esta possibilidade (na própria página de demonstração ele aceita 99:99). Acho que vai ser difícil conseguir algo como o input time (pena que poucos navegadores aceitam). Também tenho interesse nesta resposta, porque pra mudar os de data (tava usando o `date`) to sofrendo aqui, e ainda tenho os de horário pra alterar (que nem comecei :/).  Então espero que encontre(mos) uma boa resposta! :-)

Comment: Queres uma solução para browsers modernos ou antigos também? esse plugin não permite isso, mas dá para fazer uma versão "custom" se não tiveres de usar esse plugin. Vou ver se encontro um agnóstico tb.

Comment: @Sergio Não tem necessidade de compatibilidade retroativa. Vou orientar os usuários a usarem sempre as versões mais atualizadas possíveis dos respectivos navegadores. Me interessa bastante a versão *custom*.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, seu projeto emprega um padrão de 12 (am/pm) ou 24 horas?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Horas é um campo livre, mas se quiser fazer uma resposta pra 24h, ok.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pra 12h é facil restringir, usando o plugin sugerido na resposta do Guilherme Diego. Pra 24h, tem uma condicional que tá difícil de sair. Continuo tentando aqui e te aviso

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez ainda não tive tempo de acabar um "custom mask" para este caso. A ideia que estou a trabalhar é esta: http://jsfiddle.net/hqob3wxj/ faz o que queres?

Comment: A resposta correta deveria ser a do @master-oak

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tive que colocar num `pastebin` porque não me deixa puxar o source, mas os originais são:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/2.x/js/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/2.x/js/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/2.x/js/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#time").inputmask("h:s",{ "placeholder": "hh/mm" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pastebin.com/raw/5ZtAJd0v"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pastebin.com/raw/fb6hwXMD"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pastebin.com/raw/fkjwWpFs"></script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="time" value=""/> 
</div>
```

#### Mais informações aqui: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/blob/3.x/README_date.md

#### Utilizando o 3.x não consegui fazer funcionar.

Answer (score 5):

Aconselho você usar o http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Se você der uma olhada ele tem uma opção de `pattern` que pelo que entendi você consegue configurar um RegExp com o *range* de aceite pra sua mascara.

O código ficaria assim por exemplo:

```
var mask = "HH:MM",
    pattern = {
        'translation': {
            'H': {
                pattern: /[0-23]/
            },
            'M': {
                pattern: /[0-59]/
            }
        }
    };

$("#QuantidadeHoras").mask(mask, pattern);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2oxak786/

Comment: esse padrão não e apenas para   permitir que o usuario digite apenas números ?

Comment: Ok, e qual o *pattern*? É isto que quero na resposta.

Comment: var mask = "00:11",
pattern = {'translation': {
  0 : {pattern:/[0-24]/},
  1 : {pattern:/[0-59]/}
}};

$(".masktest").mask(mask, pattern);

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez http://jsfiddle.net/nrfmf3n4/1/ Só uma correção no `pattern` o correto é `[0-23]`

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Ficou esquisito. Digitei "15" e trocou pra "11".

Comment: como eu faço para ter permissão para digitar as horas 14:00, 15:00, 16:00 e etc ?

Comment: O exemplo que consta no **jsFiddle** não permite digitar **06:00** ?

Answer (score 4):

Também é possível resolver esse problema usando javascript puro, com a seguinte regex:

```
([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Entradas:

```
válidas
20:59
00:59
01:01
10:30
00:00

inválidas
24:59
30:01
00:60
05:122
```

[Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/gG6uZ0/1)

Comment: Ficou bacana, mas eu precisava dessa lógica no `<input type="text">`.

Comment: +1. Eu simplesmente joguei isso no atributo `pattern` do `input` e deu certo :)

Answer (score 3):

Deixando aqui para referencias futuras.

Este exemplo utiliza a seguinte biblioteca:
https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Nos exemplos acima, temos problemas com os códigos que utilizam esta biblioteca na forma de problemas ao gerar horários iniciados com '0', por exemplo (06:30, 08:30), portanto, vamos expandir o código um pouco:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="hora" />
```

JS:

```
var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
  return val.replace(/\D/g, '')[0] === '2' ? 'AE:CD' : 'AB:CD';
},
spOptions = {
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
      field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
    },
    translation: {
       "A": { pattern: /[0-2]/, optional: false},
       "B": { pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: false},
       "C": { pattern: /[0-5]/, optional: false},
       "D": { pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: false},
       "E": { pattern: /[0-3]/, optional: false}
    }
};

$('#hora').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);
```

O que o código acima faz é detectar se o primeiro digito da hora foi '0' ou '1' e neste caso permite que o segundo digito seja entre '0' e '9'. Caso o primeiro digito da hora seja '2', apenas permite que seja prosseguido por '0-3'. Os minutos não tem segredo, prosseguem da mesma forma.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9cvLzmfs/

Comment: Esta deveria ser a resposta aceita.

Answer (score 2):

É possível utilizar o [jquery-masked-input](/questions/tagged/jquery-masked-input), mudando a máscara com o evento `onKeyPress`, dependendo se as horas tem um valor igual a ou maior do que 20.

```js
var mask = function (val) {
    val = val.split(":");
    return (parseInt(val[0]) > 19)? "HZ:M0" : "H0:M0";
}

pattern = {
    onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
        field.mask(mask.apply({}, arguments), options);
    },
    translation: {
        'H': { pattern: /[0-2]/, optional: false },
        'Z': { pattern: /[0-3]/, optional: false },
        'M': { pattern: /[0-5]/, optional: false }
    },
    placeholder: 'hh:mm'
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#QuantidadeHoras").mask(mask, pattern);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="QuantidadeHoras" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Se vc usa a biblioteca do Pablo escobar, tem esse exemplo que utilizo

```
   $("#hora").mask("AB:CD", {
        translation: {
          "A": { pattern: /[0-2]/, optional: false},
          "B": { pattern: /[0-3]/, optional: false},
          "C": { pattern: /[0-5]/, optional: false},
          "D": { pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: false}
        }
    });
```

Testado e funcionando

Obs: cuidado com as vírgulas e aspas no js