# Máscara para hora com iMask

Tags: jquery

Estou usando esse [plugin Jquery](https://github.com/zyklus/jQuery-iMask) para formatar máscaras mas não estou conseguindo fazer o mesmo funcionar, mesmo seguindo religiosamente o exemplo existente, tentei isso, alterando um formato existente para o meu caso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dHora').iMask({
          type      : 'fixed'
        , mask      : '00:00'
        , stripMask : true
    })  
});
```

Mas a máscara não é aplicada.

Comment: Tente alterar para **99:99** (0 não é coringa para nada)

Comment: Olá @Luis Henrique, tinha alterado tanto que nem tinha percebido essa gritante falha minha, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Já viste esta pergunta -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71094/129 ?

Comment: @LuizHenrique formule uma resposta :) mesmo que simples pode ser útil, eu acho

Comment: Mas porque não usa o time do html5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta alterar os coringas definidos para a máscara:

```
00:00
```

Deve ser substituido por:

```
99:99
```

Quando você usou **0** ele não é substituido por nada por não se tratar de um coringa para o plugin que roda por trás.

Os coringas disponíveis para serem usados como máscara conforme documentação, são:

> 9 = Numeric
>
> a = Alpha
>
> x = AlphaNumeric