# Máscara "hora minuto segundo" em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

O JavaScript abaixo possui máscara `hh:mm`. Preciso de máscara no formato `hh:mm:ss`.

Alguém conhece alguma solução, ou pode me ajudar a adaptar o código abaixo?

```
function formatHora(campo, e)
{
  if (!e)
    return false;

  car = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

  if (car == 8)
    return true;

  if((((car >=48)&&(car <=57))||(car == 8)) && (campo.value.length < 7))
  {
    if (campo.value.length == 2)
      campo.value = campo.value + ':';

//    campo.value = campo.value + ':';

      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Outra forma de fazer: [Máscara em JS para Validação de Horas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71094/91)

Answer (score 1):

Funcionou, fiz ainda alguns pequenos ajustes, mas iluminou meu caminho, muito obrigado.

onde estava:

```
if((((car >=48)&&(car <=57))||(car == 8)) && (campo.value.length < 9)){
```

ficou:

```
if((((car >=48)&&(car <=57))||(car == 8)) && (campo.value.length < 8)){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatHora(campo, e){

if (!e){ return false; }

car = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

if (car == 8){ return true; }

if((((car >=48)&&(car <=57))||(car == 8)) && (campo.value.length < 9)){

  /* É SÓ ACRESCENTAR ESSE (|| campo.value.length == 5) NO IF ABAIXO */

  if (campo.value.length == 2 || campo.value.length == 5){
    campo.value = campo.value + ':';
  }

  return true;
}
return false;
}
```